# Today widget in iOS10 height issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set the height for the today widget in iOS10 but it doesn't worked. It was working before in iOS9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Set the display mode to NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
}
```

2) implement given protocal method

```
[![func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize){
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
    }
    else {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 200);
    }
}
```

[image]